# Homework, trying to learn recursion is this correct?

Tags: recursion

Ok, recursion is giving me "coders block" I have 2 homework assignments this week, one of them is simply the following..

**Design a function that accepts an integer argument and returns the sum of all the integers from
1 up to the number passed as an argument. For example, if 50 is
passed
as an argument, the fu
nction
will return the sum
of 1, 2, 3, 4,
...
.50
. Use the recursion to calculate the sum.**

This is my solution... am I understanding how this works? The book is teaching us via some fake psuedocode so I know it's not "real" code....

```
Function Integer SumAll(Integer Number)

  If Number > 0 Then
   Return Number + SumAll(Number-1)      
  Else
   Return 0
  End If

End Function
```

OK I think this is it, I wrote this in c++ to test it out.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int SumAll(int Number){

  if (Number > 0) {
    return Number + SumAll(Number-1);
  }
}

int main(){
  cout<<SumAll(2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try doing a walkthrough. Are you actually using the value of Number in a useful way?

Comment: Well it's the integer argument... and the value that stops the recursion from being an infinite loop right?

Comment: True as far as it goes. Consider the addition statement. Is `Sum` initialized? What should you add to `SumAll(Number-1)` to get `SumAll(Number)`? Remember that this function will be called many times, and the value of `Sum` is not retained between calls.

Comment: It should be 5 right? because that's the original number it starts as?

Comment: ALright! I think I got it. I wrote the same thing in C++ just to test it out... this is correct?

`#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int SumAll(int Number){

int Sum = Number;

if (Number > 0) {

 return Sum + SumAll(Number-1);

}

}

int main(){



cout<<SumAll(2);

return 0;



}`

Comment: @Owen sorry for the offtopic but I'm really interested. Can you tell the name of the book and/or the author. I'm really interested on something specifically focused on recursion. Also, this pseudo code - it doesn't seem to be from the book. At least I hope so. Every recursion need something called - `Border case`(es) but here it's missing.

Comment: Book is called Programming Logic and Design, written by Tony Gaddis, it's for the "Intro to Programming Course at my college.

This code isn't from the book, it's my code, from the homework assignment. I read the whole chapter, I dont see anything about border cases....

Comment: @Leron:  Base case, not border case.  And in the OP's pseudo code (not C++ code), the base case is *implied* to be `if( Number <= 0 ) { return sum; }`

Comment: Well, I've seen it as `border case` too, but guess `base` is the correct term. However at least for me it's cleaner to do `(if Number == 1) return 1;`

Comment: I fixed the pseudocode. It's correct now too right? Also, thank you all very much for the help. I almost feel like IM finally getting a grasp on recursion.

Comment: @Owen In this case you don't need to initialize new variable (`Sum`) you already have `Number` work with it!

Comment: At some point you have to stop asking people whether it's correct and [get out the compiler and find out yourself](http://ideone.com/5rsvGa).

Comment: I agree with the compiler part, but this class.. it's all fake code, and they want it wrote in fake code, so you can't ever actually test it. If I didn't already know the basics of writing C++ I would NEVER be able to actually test anything to see if it truly works. Frankly I kind of hate the class for that very reason. But it's required for my degree....

Comment: @Leron Ok I corrected and refined it based off your advice. This is what you mean? Now I totally understand.

Comment: I'm not familiar with c++, but when number is <= 0, did you miss a return? From my view, your code is missing the "base case" of recursion. If number<=0, you should `return 0`, isn't it?

Comment: @LeoLaw I don't know to be honest. I tested it with a negative number and I still get 1 as the return value, for whatever weird reason. You are right though, I need a way to make it handle negatives. I've never had any formal training with C++, mostly just dabbling while I take this intro class so I can actually see stuff compiled.

Comment: @Owen, if you add `return 0` in the end of `SumAll`, will it still return 1 for you? I'm afraid there is some "smart" design in c++ that it auto return 1 for function calls.

Comment: @LeoLaw Nope then it returns 0 as "intended" Thank you very much for the advice, this community has been really great for my first day on here.

Comment: @Owen Well, maybe there's some stylistic shades to it but the `baes cases` are important and they prevent your recursion to turn into infinite loop. Because of that I like those to be at the strat of my code. So in other words instead of `if ( Number > 0 )`.. I would go with `if ( Number == 1 ) { return 1; } return number + SumAll(Number-1);`. Maybe both way works but when you start with your base case - if the Number equals 1 return it's more understandable to read at least for me. Also in more complex algorithms you will have multiple base cases so I thin it's good to put them all in 1 place

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ code is buggy because the base case needs to be treated in the recursive function itself.

Your pseudocode is basically correct except that it doesn't work when Number < 0; you should really have an error message in that case.

I agree with the comments that you cannot possibly work in the dark; use a real programming language. Your pseudocode looks a lot like Pascal, so maybe you can use [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org) here. Otherwise, I'd recommend [Python](https://www.python.org).

In Python 3, the code would look like this:

```python
def sum_all(number):
    if number > 1:
        return number + sum_all(number-1)
    elif number == 1: # base case
        return 1
    else:
        raise Exception("negative number")

print(sum_all(10))
```

which would correctly return 55.

When I made my studies, the teacher also used some kind of pseudocode similar to Pascal. We agreed very early on that I would use Turbo Pascal instead, and that helped me a lot because I was able to test things on the PC.